# Haskell IO averaging function IO, pure vs unpure attempt

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a program where the user keeps inputting numbers and will output the average once they input a negative number
This is my attempt in keeping the `pure separate from unpure` 
can someone give me tips in fixing this code, and pure and unpure separation tips.

```
getFloat :: IO Float
getFloat = do line <- getLine
              return (read line:: Float)
```

"impure part"

```
average :: IO Float
average = do x <- getFloat
             return((fst help x)/(snd help x))
```

"pure part"

```
help x 
    |x>=0 = (x+sum1, 1+ counter)
    |otherwise = (sum1 , counter)
    where 
    sum1 = 0.0
    counter = 0.0
```

I get this error

```
.hs:45:26:
    Couldn't match expected type `(t0 -> Float, b0)'
                with actual type `t1 -> (t1, t2)'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `help'
    In the first argument of `(/)', namely `(fst help x)'
    In the first argument of `return', namely
      `((fst help x) / (snd help x))'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Looks like a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is a silly way to tell you that `help` is not a tuple, so the application `fst help` is wrong.

Comment: I recommend to beginners to write smaller expressions, so that the error messages hopefully get less confusing. Along the lines of `let a = ..; let b = ...; return $ a / b` (substitute ; by new lines)

Comment: @Ingo: That won't help a lot unless you also add type signatures there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at what's wrong with your code, before looking at how to fix it.

The function `getFloat` is fine, and does exactly what you think it does.

The function `help` does *not* do what you think it does. As it is, when fed a value `x` it just returns the tuple `(x,1.0)` if `x > 0`, otherwise it returns `(0.0,0.0)`.. You could give it the type:

```
help :: Double -> (Double,Double)
```

whereas I guess you intend it to have the type

```
help :: [Double] -> (Double,Double)
```

You could write your intended version like this:

```
help xs = (sum xs, fromIntegral (length xs))
```

In the function `average` you have the expression `fst help x`, which is parenthesised like this: `(fst help) x`. This is the reason for your error message: you can only apply `fst` to something of type `(a,b)` but you are trying to apply it to something of type `Double -> (Double,Double)`, so an error is thrown.

If I was going to write this function I'd probably do something like this:

```
import Data.List (takeWhile) -- take elements from a list while predicate is satisfied

avg xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)

main = do numbers <- fmap (takeWhile (>0) . map read . words) getContents
          return (avg numbers)
```

The function `avg` is pure. The function `takeWhile (>0) . map read . words` is also pure, and could be factored like this:

```
helper :: String -> [Double]
helper = takeWhile (>0) . map read . words

main = do numbers <- fmap helper getContents
          return (avg numbers)
```

This illustrates a general principle - use impure code to input and output the values you're going to be working with, and use pure code to transform those values.

Comment: `fmap (avg . helper) getContents`

Comment: Yup, that's a neater way of writing it!

Comment: I wonder if OP didn't actually want to accumulate the results progressively, rather than using a list.